# Reprogramming yourself

Tags: magic

You don't know this, but in the program that is your consciousness there are break points. I.e., points in which the program stops, and you have a chance to reflect on it and perhaps change it.

The way this works is that you suddenly have an out-of-body experience, in which you realize that time has stopped and you have an ability to change certain things about yourself (see details below). You know that once you 'resume' yourself you will forget that this ever happened, and you don't remember it ever happening before although you are aware it's possible that it had.

#### What you can do:

- Erase / alter memories
- Change some of your biases (e.g. improve your attitude towards certain people/ experiences) inc. instincts
- Put something in your 'think queue' (e.g. recall something, consider an idea - perhaps this idea)
- Think long and hard about things so when you resume you have an answer

#### Limitations:

- You can't stay in this limbo forever - few hours at most.
- The break points happen at an individual distribution. for some it's every few minutes, for some once a month. This can't be changed.

**If this was true, what effect would it have on your life?**

things I considered so far:

- If it happens to you a lot, people will consider you extremely sharp smart.
- people will try to erase traumas, which might backlash and cause them to return as no lessons were learned.

Comment: While a very interesting premise, this is very, very broad. You could write a book on all the effects this would have --- no answer can really do it justice. In brief though imagine a much more complicated, technological world if people can always self-improve.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure this doesn't already happen in real life? Do you remember that you saw or experienced something horrible that changed your life forever, but you can't remember the actual sight or experience? Well?

It's called sleep.

Comment: You forget your dreams but in them you can't change anything in the waking world, so I don't really see how that's the same

Comment: First of all, I didn't say dreams, I said sleep. Second, I don't understand what you mean by "can't change anything in the waking world." I don't see anything about changing physical reality in your question, and events that take place in your brain while you're unconscious do have a drastic effect on your thoughts and actions in the "waking world."

Comment: I often worry at a problem as I try to sleep and wake in the morning knowing what I will do.

Comment: @BrianLami has a point... sleep is the brain reorganizing itself.